# Chatter free user - Can be added to public groups

Tags: chatter

Is it possible to add chatter free user to public groups?

I believe it is not possibel, but still wanted to confirm it...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately a Chatter Free User does not have access to any data so there would not be a point to add them to a Public Group. What is your use case?